# Showing a unique result based on options selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple quiz in HTML/CSS and plain Javascript. There are three questions with two options each, so there are eight possible combinations of answers, and therefore results. You can only pick one option per question.

This is how I am currently assigning a result to each combination in Javascript. The input is done through HTML.

```
function GetResult(){
var result;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, i < inputs.length, i++){
if(inputs[i].checked){
result = result + inputs[i].value;
}}

if(result == 'NaturalHistoricalRelaxed'){
//result A
}
if(result == 'NaturalHistoricalFast'){
//result B
}
if(result == 'NaturalModernRelaxed'){
//result C
}
if(result == 'NaturalModernFast'){
//result D
}
if(result == 'UrbanHistoricalRelaxed'){
//result E
}
if(result == 'UrbanHistoricalFast'){
//result F
}
if(result == 'UrbanModernRelaxed'){
//result G
}
if(result == 'UrbanModernFast'){
//result H
}
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of assigning each result to each combination?

I know that many people would tell me to use a Javascript library, but I don't want to, so please do not write answers like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar enough with JavaScript to write out the code while I am travelling, but I can at least describe a simple algorithm to do so generally in a faster and slightly simpler way. I here assume that you have access to the raw results and don't need to re-interpret them from the collected string.

For each answer we assign a 0 or 1 to the result, and then join them together as a bit mask, by shifting each answer by the 0-indexed numbering of the question it is an answer to. You can then construct an array of all the possible results, 
and when you want to know which result a response corresponds to, you can just construct an integer from the above bit mask and use it as an index for the array's result you want. If you have unique results for every response, then this is about as good as you can do (remember you can put a function in the array and call it if you want to do the compilation lazily). If you can construct the results from some kind of pattern, then you can find the right indexes by filtering the indexes with and based bit masked (with not applied to the result if you want the ones which have 0's in those masks).

Comment: You are describing a 'nominal' value. I like solutions that use existing structs to store 'complex' data. Unfortunately, I am out of votes.

Comment: Is it just me, or are bit masks not very developer friendly when it comes to readability and debugging? I get that they are very good for performance, but would a simple dictionary not suffice in this case, and be much easier to use? Or am I just too much of a simple web developer to understand their benefit?

Answer (score 1):

when you have many if condition with one case value, you can use switch case syntax

```
switch (result) {
  case 'NaturalHistoricalRelaxed':
    //result A;
    break;
  case 'NaturalHistoricalFast':
    //result B;
    break;
  case 'NaturalModernRelaxed':
     //result C;
    break;
  case 'NaturalModernFast':
    //result D;
    break;
  case 'UrbanHistoricalRelaxed':
    //result E;
    break;
  case 'UrbanHistoricalFast':
   //result F;
    break;
  case 'UrbanModernRelaxed':
    //result G;
    break;
  case 'UrbanModernFast':
    //result H;
}
```

Comment: This is an example of why best practice in general questions are off-topic. Since we don't know what `//result A` is we don't know if your switch or a dictionary / object would be better. Take `{'NaturalHistoricalRelaxed': 'result A'}[result]`. Since I don't know if your advice is good or bad I'm hesitant to upvote it.

Comment: It was very thought-provoking, I didn't look at it that way.
but i know, if we have many if for one unique value, it will be better replace to switch case, may be it is not true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your code entirely. What is happening inside each conditional? What doe you mean by "assigning each result to each combination"? I'll assume you are trying to select a certain value based on a combination of answers, cause that makes the most sense to me.

First off, the result string could be composed in a cleaner way with modern javascript (imo). I would probably go for something like this, mostly because I find it to be more readable:

```
const checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
const answerKey = Array.from(checkedInputs, input => input.value).join('');
```

To then select the desired value based on this key, it would probably be cleaner to work with a dictionary. Something like this:

```
const resultDictionary = {
   NaturalHistoricalRelaxed: 'result A',
   NaturalHistoricalFast: 'result B'
   // ...
}

const result = resultDictionary[answerKey];
```

No ugly chain of conditionals, and much easier to maintain if you have to change something. You could even pull in that dictionary from a JSON file or an API or something, and make the code work on multiple quizes that way.

I hope I interpreted your question correctly and my answer makes sense. Feel free to ask if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Really @Peilonrayz? An open question with +1 score and two prior answers and you choose to downvote just me? How am I supposed to know this is off topic (according to you)? Perhaps you should close the question then, in stead off slapping people on the wrist that try to be helpful... Way to build a community!

Comment: The question is +3/-2 and has 4 close votes attached to it. I can appreciate that you can't see this. Additionally my comment on Mehrdad's answer said this is an off-topic question. Additionally if anything I targeted Mehrdad, as I systematically edited, commented and voted on all of their posts. Again I can appreciate that you didn't know this. But I'd appreciate it if you didn't accuse me of nonsense based on nothing more than a hunch.

Comment: You are probably right, I shouldn't have lashed out like that. Please accept my apologies @Peilonrayz, it's just that it's the second time I get slapped on the wrist in as many answers, and this time I really don't see how the question is off topic (perhaps you care to explain). I get the feeling things have changed around here, and I'm not sure I like the patrolling vibe I get...

Comment: It's ok Pevara. I could have made my initial comment better too, to avoid a needless confrontation. I am sorry. I can understand that it's not nice to feel like you're being policed. In this case the question is missing context to give an accurate answer, for example it's impossible for me to know which of your answer or Mehrdad's answer is better for the OP. We have made this off-topic as we have had problems with OPs becoming hostile to answerers that just want to help but weren't given all the information.